# Why won't all the ids get changed though I selected all of them by using the # idname?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*I am completely new to coding in general. I've started with the very basics of HTML, CSS and JavaScript.*

I have two paragraphs:

```html
<p id="title1">Change this</p>
<p id="title1"> Change this too! </p>
```

While the first one gets automatically changed by:

```js
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    $('#title1').html('Changed!');
</script>
```

the second one doesn't. But shouldn't it? Since all `#title1` are being changed?

I have the same problem for the `onclick` version. The first paragraph gets changed when clicking on it, the second doesn't.

```html
<p id="title3" onclick="sayGoodbye();">Toggle this Hello - Goodbye</p>
<p id="title3" onclick="sayGoodbye();">Thing to click on</p>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sayGoodbye(){
        $("#title3").html('Goodbye');
        $("#title3").click(function(){
            $("#title3").html("Hello again!");
            $("#title3").off("click");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique.

Comment: The problem is your `id` attributes. They must be unique - you can't have multiple elements share them. To do that, use a `class` instead

Comment: Also note that you shouldn't use the outdated `on*` event attributes. Use unobtrusive click handlers, as you are in your second example, just place them within `document.ready`, not their own function

Comment: Also, I'm trying to keep track of my progress in one place. So I'd be very happy about any advice! :) [link](http://atechkat.blogspot.com)

Comment: Three people upvoted a question asking why duplicate ID's doesn't work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you select an element by its id, only the first one gets selected because you're only supposed to use one id on one element! Each id should only ever be used once on a page!

If you need to get a bunch of elements together 'by' something, do it 'by class'.

```js
$(".title1").html("Changed!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="title1">Change this</p>
<p class="title1"> Change this too! </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

**ID attribute has to be unique for each HTML tag**. You can use `class` attribute to act on multiple tags.

Answer (score 2):

- The `id` attribute should be unique at least in the same level child tree.
- Use `class` instead and listen to `.click()` with `$(this)` to get
  current clicked element.
- If you want to call a function using `onclick` attribute pass clicked element to it using `this` like `onclick="sayGoodbye(this);"`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="title3" onclick="sayGoodbye(this);">Toggle this Hello - Goodbye</p>
<p class="title3" onclick="sayGoodbye(this);">Thing to click on</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function sayGoodbye(t){
        $(t).html('Goodbye');
        $(t).click(function(){
            $(this).html("Hello again!");
            $(this).off("click");
        });
    }
</script>
```